# Out Of memory Error while sending the large bitmap to server

Tags: android, image

My question might be old but I am suffering because of this issue from last 2 weeks and now its too much, in my application I need to send large image bitmap to server and I am doing this by below coding:

```
  BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bfOptions.inDither=false;                     //Disable Dithering mode
                bfOptions.inPurgeable=true;                   //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
                bfOptions.inInputShareable=true;              //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
                bfOptions.inTempStorage=new byte[32 * 1024];


                File file=new File(TabGroupActivity.path);
                FileInputStream input=null;
                try {
                    input = new FileInputStream(TabGroupActivity.path);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    //TODO do something intelligent
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(input!=null)
                {

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bfOptions);

                }

                  Matrix mat = new Matrix();//removing rotations

                   if(TabGroupActivity.rotation==90 ||  TabGroupActivity.rotation==270)
                    {
                        mat.setRotate(90);
                    }
                    else if(TabGroupActivity.rotation==0 || TabGroupActivity.rotation==180)
                    {
                        mat.setRotate(0);
                    }
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);

                       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                int height= bitmap.getHeight();
                int width=bitmap.getWidth();

                     {
                //formula for calculating aspect ratio 

        float k= (float) height/width;
         newHeight =Math.round(620*k);
             }


        byte[] buffer=new byte[10];

        while(input.read(buffer)!=-1)
        {
             bos.write(buffer);
        }

                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , 620, newHeight, true);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);
                byte[] imageData = bos.toByteArray();
                ContentBody cb = new ByteArrayBody(imageData, "image/jpg", "image1.jpeg");

                  input.close();
```

but after sending 2,3 images I am getting out of memory error on `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` please help me the resolve this issue the main thing I can not re-size or crop image, I need to send good quality image only to server.

Answer (score 0):

Recycle your bitmaps every time you are done with them by calling `bitmap.recycle()`, this should help a bit. Also optimize your code a bit; this part:

```
           if(TabGroupActivity.rotation==90 ||  TabGroupActivity.rotation==270)
            {
                mat.setRotate(90);
            }
            else if(TabGroupActivity.rotation==0 || TabGroupActivity.rotation==180)
            {
                mat.setRotate(0);
            }
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

You can reduce to

```
           if(TabGroupActivity.rotation==90 ||  TabGroupActivity.rotation==270)
            {
                mat.setRotate(90);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);

            }
```

So you don't have to create a new bitmap in every case.

Also, you can experiment with the `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` to get smaller images.

Comment: Hello Jave i am recycleing bitmap every time and the error i am getting on this line bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bfOptions);

Comment: and i can not resize image as i need to send large bitmap to server